# Reactive Search MultiDropdownList not finding dataField

Tags: reactjs, reactivesearch

I have the follow Reactive search set up:

```
<ReactiveBase app="dailies_prod" url={elasticSearch}>
      <CategorySearch
      componentId="Searchbox"
      dataField={['dept', 'artist']}
      placeholder="Search"
      className="asset-search-field"
    />
    <MultiDropdownList
      componentId="Artists"
      dataField="artist"
      showCount={true}
      placeholder="Artists"
      URLParams={true}
      react={{
        and: ['Searchbox'],
      }}
      className="artist-list"
    />
    <MultiDropdownList
      componentId="Departments"
      dataField="dept"
      showCount={true}
      placeholder="Departments"
      URLParams={true}
      react={{
        and: ['Searchbox'],
      }}
      className="department-list"
    />
      <ResultCard
        componentId="Results"
        dataField="timeSubmitted"
        react={{
          and: ['Searchbox', 'Departments', 'Artists'],
        }}
        onData={asset => {
          let component = (
            <Dailies
              name={asset.name}
              dept={asset.dept}
              author={asset.artist}
              image={asset.thumbnail}
            />
          );
          return {
            description: component,
          };
        }}
        showResultStats={false}
        className="dailies-result-card "
      />
    </ReactiveBase>
```

There is an artist field on my index dailie_prod. I can search against that field in the CategorySearch and find results. However the MultiDropDownList that I am trying to filter artists with, will not render at all.

Because I can search against this field, it leads me to believe that there is nothing wrong with the index. If I swap artists for another field, the same MultiDropDownList code will render and populate.

Any idea on what is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I needed `artist.keyword`